# How to declare local type augmentation?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Typescript gives me the following error: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Vue'

I know I can do this to add a global property :

```
declare module "vue/types/vue" {
    interface Vue {
        name: string;
    }
}
```

But I only want that property for my Tab component.
How to I make a local interface for my tab component with property name on it?

`Tab.vue`:

```
@Component
export default class Tab extends Vue {
    @Prop({required : true, type: String}) public name!: string;
}
```

`Tabs.vue`:

```
@Component
export default class Tabs extends Vue {
  private mounted(): void {
    // tslint:disable-next-line: no-console
    this.$children.forEach((tab) => console.log(tab.name));
  }
}
```

Ok I found a solution :

```
export interface ITab extends Vue {
  name: string;
}

this.$children.forEach(tab=> {
  console.log((tab as ITab).name);
});
```